# Camel file component - access denied

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am trying to use the Camel *file component* to write a file ...the Camel code is :

```
<to uri="file:exports?fileName=customer.csv&amp;fileExist=Append&amp;jailStartingDirectory=false"/>
```

This results in the following error in the log :

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: The access to D:\development\ie-projects\pim-rod-class-091323-0051\exports is denied.
```

I have tried adjusting folder permissions for the ***exports*** folder  ...no help.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you using spring security?